# I have two do blocks that need to show a list of posts without repeating the first block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a column of 2 post with only images showing and the rest in a column of 4 displaying the rest of the posts without repeating the first two. Not too sure how to do that.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  # the 2 is what makes only 2 post show
  @posts = Post.most_hit(1.day.ago, 2)
  @all_posts = Post.most_hit(1.day.ago)
 end
end

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <%= image_tag attachment_url(post, :image) %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<% @all_posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <%= image_tag attachment_url(post, :image) %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering you'd need pagination sooner or later, you'd rather do this at the db level:

```
def index
  # the 2 is what makes only 2 post show
  @posts = Post.most_hit(1.day.ago, 2)
  @all_posts = Post.where.not(id: @posts.map(&:id)).most_hit(1.day.ago)
end
```

Or if you want to use arrays only:

```
def index
  @all_posts = Post.most_hit(1.day.ago)
  @posts = @all_posts.slice!(0, 2)
end
```